In Android, What should be done when application is opened via file, upon pressing overview button my app should be seen and not the file manager app?
I was trying to open few types of files (.txt, .pdf) in Android phones. There are scenarios where I want to understand how this type of variation can have been done.
In the files application of Google, if I tap on the .txt file and click on HTML viewer and if we see the task view the HTML viewer opens in the files app itself but if we open a .pdf file then it would not be opened in the files app, but it would be opened in its own application.
This is the txt file screenshot (opened in HTML Viewer) below which looks within the files app itself. If you see above it is showing Files App.

But for pdf files, it is different if you see as below:

My Question is how a pdf application is able to separate this out?
My application considers binary files with a custom extension which has an intent-filter as shown below for launcher activity. If I want to have similar experience as how PDF app is doing what should be added more?
Will it be in the intent-filter, I am not sure. Can somebody help here?
<intent-filter>
    <action   android:name     = "android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name     = "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data     android:mimeType = "*/*"/>
    <data     android:scheme   = "content"/>
    <data     android:host     = "*"/>


you need to understand how intents are working in android, here is some documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters
